# Android Gradle assemble all APKs for a flavour group

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-productflavors

I have several flavor groups in my application:

- sport (soccer, rubgy)
- serverType (development, qualification, production)
- commercialType (locked, unlocked, regular)

Currently when reaching a release state, I make a global build of the app using `gradle assembleRelease`

As a result I get 18 APKs as a result of all flavor combinations.

I know I could build one specific combination with e.g. the `assembleSoccerLockedProductionRelease`. However, for a release build I sometimes would like to only build the combinations related to one or more flavor groups. For instance:

- All APKs for production server
- All APKs for production server and only regular commercialType

Is that possible?